# Is it possible to start off on SharePoint Online and then when SP 2019 comes go hybrid Online/Prem?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

Is it possible to start off on SharePoint Online and then when SP 2019 comes go hybrid Online/Prem?
If so, would there be particular dilemmas that would bring up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, though I'm unsure of why you would, you would simply need to use a migration tool like Sharegate to copy down any content you wanted. You can start out other things as hybrid, such as hybrid taxonomy or OneDrive for Business.

Comment: Trevor thank you. It's because they are eager to get on SharePoint and waiting for 2019 is too long a wait for them. Also Online makes it easy to make portals for external clients , but they also want onPrem to customize to their hearts content with InfoPath forms and workflows and keep some data restricted to onPrem only,. Please tell me, does that sound justified?